# Does any Intuit Anywhere SDK use a common data structure?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

So we are all familiar with using syntax like the below;
   Intuit.Ipp.Data.**Qbo**.Bill for on-line
and
   Intuit.Ipp.Data.**Qbd**.Bill for desktop

My application talks to both on-line and desktop, as I am sure most do, and I find myself coding a lot of duplicate code because of "Qbo" and "Qbd".

So my question is; do any of the available SDKs use a common "data" structure for both on-line and desktop so you don't have to code everything twice?

Thanks Much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freddy,
The service and SDK for v2 have separate code paths for QuickBooks Online and QuickBooks for Windows. The v3 implementation of the service and the sdk unifies both Desktop and Online, so it is less code for you to write.

If you are interested in participating in the v3 Beta you can sign up here:
http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2013/03/application-for-early-access-to-quickbooks-api-v3.html

regards
Jarred

Answer (score 1):

> do any of the available SDKs use a common "data" structure for both
>   on-line and desktop so you don't have to code everything twice?

**Right now, no, there is no unifed API.**

Intuit Anywhere v2 data service has separate APIs (as you've seen) for QuickBooks Online vs. for QuickBooks for Windows, that differ significantly in implementation.

The only other alternative (the SDK) also has two similar, but significantly different implementations.

The good news is that v3 of the Intuit Anywhere/Intuit Partner Platform data services *will* have a unified API. Intuit is working on that, and it should be available soon.